# Java multiple Regex Validation

Tags: java, regex

I'm new to java and I'm trying to validate user input using a regex.

I need to validate two patterns :

- version
- version-1.xy when x & y are digits

below is my pattern but somehow it is not working..

```
String versionRegex  = "^version-1.[1-9][1-9]|version";
```

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Show us examples where it is not working

Comment: You need to escape the `.` as `\.`. Everything else seems correct

Comment: How do you know that "it's not working" ? What input are you giving, what is the outcome, and what did you expect the outcome to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will support version / version-1.xy / VERSION / VERSION-1.xy

```
String versionRegex  = "(?i)^version(-1\\.[1-9][1-9])?";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String versionRegex  = "(?i)^version(-1\\.[1-9][1-9])?";
```

`.` needs to be escaped in java with `\\`, and `(?i)` to support case insensitive matching.

Comment: I'd suggest `^version(-1\\.[1-9][1-9])?`

Comment: thanks!, in case I wanna support capital letters ? what should I add..
eg. VERSION-1.xy or VERSION

Comment: @jawmar You need add `(?i)` in front of the regexp and it will becoem case insensitive